# Using cbuffer without specifying a register

Tags: directx, hlsl

I generally use cbuffer with specifying 'b#' register in hlsl, but i recently found out it is fine that i don't have to specify it for some of cases. so it brings me a question.
What exactly is the difference between

```
cbuffer
{
   float4x4 someMatrix = (float4x4)0;
}
```

And

```
cbuffer : register(b0)
{
   float4x4 someMatrix = (float4x4)0;
}
```

Is it automatically bound on b0 register when compiled?

Comment: It will choose automatically first free slot from b0 to b14. I personally wouldn't rely on that since it seems more error-prone than specifying it explicitly but yes, you don't need to specify it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler assigns the unspecified buffers to a register in a 'first-fits' policy. You have to use shader reflection at runtime to determine exactly where it's bound. See [D3DReflect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcompiler/nf-d3dcompiler-d3dreflect) and [ID3D11ShaderReflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11shader/nn-d3d11shader-id3d11shaderreflection) / [ID3D12ShaderReflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12shader/nn-d3d12shader-id3d12shaderreflection).

> You would probably use `cbuffer MyCB` and then use the `GetConstantBufferByName` method to find it rather than the unnamed cbuffer for reflection.

This was a feature of HLSL used for the legacy [Effects](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) system.

For modern usage, you generally explicitly assign the binding so you can avoid switching the binding every time you change shaders.